# Filter a CSV file with multiple conditions using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, csv

Here is a small sample of data in a CSV file that needs to be filtered to remove all lines that contain Branch 102 or Name equals Admin.

DataSource.csv

```
branch,ID,name
102,11056,Jones
103,11057,Henry
102,22000,Admin
103,22001,Admin
102,22002,White
103,22003,George
```

Here is the first version my PowerShell script, demo.ps1, that works -

```
$path = "C:\users\knot22\PowerShell"

Import-CSV "$($path)\DataSource.csv" | Where Branch -NotLike '*102*' | Where Name -NotLike '*Admin*' |
Export-CSV "$($path)\DataTarget.csv" -NoTypeInformation -UseQuotes Never
```

The resulting output of DataTarget.csv is -

```
branch,ID,name
103,11057,Henry
103,22003,George
```

However, I'd like to modify demo.ps1 so that the conditions are in a single `Where` block.  I've tried this

```
$path = "C:\users\knot22\PowerShell"

Import-CSV "$($path)\DataSource.csv" | Where Branch -NotLike '*102*' -or Name -NotLike '*Admin*' |
Export-CSV "$($path)\DataTarget.csv" -NoTypeInformation -UseQuotes Never
```

but it results in an error

> "Cannot bind parameter because parameter 'NotLike' is specified more
> than once. To provide multiple values to parameters that can accept
> multiple values, use the array syntax. For example, "-parameter
> value1,value2,value3".

This error message implies that the multiple conditions are intended for one parameter.  In the use case above, the multiple conditions apply to different parameters.

Is there a way to modify the syntax in the second version of demo.ps1 that attempts to combine the conditions with `-and` so that it runs successfully?  I'm looking to keep the syntax concise.

Also, I'm using PowerShell 7.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`Where-Object` cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object?view=powershell-7.3#example-6-use-multiple-conditions) (alias `Where`) has two distinct modes of filtering - one for simple property comparison (aka. [simplified syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Simplified_Syntax?view=powershell-7.3), which is what you're currently using), and one for more complex filtering scenarios.

For the latter, you'll need to supply a scriptblock that is then used as a predicate against each input item:

```
Where { $_.Branch -notlike '*102*' -or $_.Name -notlike '*Admin*' }
```

Beware that this isn't the equivalent of your current pipeline - for that, you'll want to use the `-and` operator:

```
Where { $_.Branch -notlike '*102*' -and $_.Name -notlike '*Admin*' }
```